# How to use pass ajax data that is displaying in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I have a question, that I can't seem to find the 'best' solution for my question.. I have an AJAX call that displays data in the DOM, via jQuery.

JSON

```
[{
    "id":"123"
},
{   "id":"456"
}]
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get/data',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{}',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(data, function(i) {
               html += '<p>My ID: ' + data[i].id + '</p>';
            }
            $('#id').append(html);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```

As you can see I am displaying that data here. I would like to pass that ID to another AJAX call by selecting a checkbox and pushing a button or perhaps clicking a link. Whats the best way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:** I apologize, my actual issue is related to array data. I have updated the code. I am displaying an JSON array in the html now, and I want to pass the id of the user/row that I click?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: So set your id into a empty global variable and on first ajax success assign value into it. On you second dom event like checkbox/button click call second ajax with passing that value with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var resid;
     $.ajax({
           url: 'get/data',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: '{}',
           success: function(data) {
                resid = data.id;
                var html = '';
                html += '<p>My ID: ' + data.id + '</p>'; $('#id').append(html);
           },
           error: function(err){
               console.log(err); 
           }

      });

     $('link').click(function () {
       // pass id to second ajax
     });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I apologize, but the original question isn't quite asking what I am looking for. Can you check the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

try jquery-template
https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template
hope help you